# table of unique observations in R

Tags: r, unique, factors

I have two factor variables - in data.frame called "data"  - looking like this:

```
brand  Country
 "A"    "ITA"
 "A"    "ITA"
 "C"    "SPA"
 "B"    "POR"
 "C"    "SPA"
 "B"    "POR"
 "A"    "ITA"
 "D"    "ITA"
 "E"    "SPA"
 "D"    "ITA"
```

and I'd like to get a table listing the number of unique `brands` by `country`.
Following the example it should be:

```
# of unique brands  Country
        2             "ITA"
        2             "SPA"
        1             "POR"
```

First, I tried:

```
data$var <- with(data, ave(brand, Country, FUN = function(x){length(unique(x))}))
```

but it doesn't work with factors, so I converted my factors:

```
data$brand_t<-as.character(data$brand)
data$Country_t<-as.character(data$Country)
```

and then again:

```
data$var <- with(data, ave(brand_t, Country_t, FUN = function(x){length(unique(x))}))
```

Now, if I apply `unique(data$var)` I get `"2", "2", "1"` which is correct, but I'm not able to get the table I want.
Probably silly, but I cannot work it out.

I also wonder if there's a smarter way to do it using factors instead.

Thanks once again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are two quick approaches using [`data.table` v >= 1.9.5](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) or `dplyr`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, uniqueN(brand), by = Country]
```

Or

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Country) %>%
  summarise(n = n_distinct(brand))
```

Or with base R

```
aggregate(brand ~ Country, df, function(x) length(unique(x)))
```

Or

```
tapply(df$brand, df$Country, function(x) length(unique(x)))
```

---

Or if you like base R simple syntax and your data set isn't too big, you could combine approaches as in

```
aggregate(brand ~ Country, df, uniqueN)
```

Or

```
aggregate(brand ~ Country, df, n_distinct)
```

Comment: Thanks. Also, it is fruitful for me to look at different solutions. What is the meaning of '%>%' in 'dplyr'?

Comment: It is a piping operator take a look [here](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) under **Chaining**

Comment: `aggregate` in an answer with "data.table" and "dplyr"? Where's `by`? The shock! The horror! :-)

Comment: @AnandaMahto I like `aggregate` simple syntax, even better option would be `aggregate(brand ~ Country, df, uniqueN)` or `aggregate(brand ~ Country, df, n_distinct)` :)

Comment: How fast is `unique`? Why not `aggregate(brand ~ Country, unique(mydf), length)`?

Comment: @AnandaMahto, that's a nice one, never thought of doing it that way. `unique` is one of the most optimized functions in base R, so this one should be nice.

Comment: Just did some rudimentary tests. It's slow. On 1M rows, my `aggregate` suggestion takes about 19 seconds, my present answer takes about 1.5 seconds, and "dplyr" takes about 0.4 seconds. Haven't tested "data.table" yet since I don't have the right version installed.

Comment: @ AmandaMahto using `aggregate(brand ~ Country, unique(mydf), length)` I get the frequency of all the unique values, not the number of unique values, that instead I get with `aggregate(brand ~ Country, df, function(x) length(unique(x)))`  - I wonder why. Thanks a lot for all of your comments, it's really educational. I'll keep testing your codes.

Comment: @ DavidArendburg: I could not find `uniqueN` and `n_distinct`

Comment: Did you look in the link I've attached in the answer for `data.table` GitHub version? Also, make sure you have the most recent `dplyr` version by reinstalling or updating.

Comment: In other words, just run `library(devtools);
install_github("Rdatatable/data.table", build_vignettes = FALSE)` in a new R session and then load `data.table` again

Comment: @DavidArenburg  I'll do it. Thanks for all.

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you can try `table` in conjunction with `unique` and `colSums`, like this:

```
colSums(table(unique(mydf)))
# ITA POR SPA 
#   2   1   2
```